# Immutable JS lazy Seq chained method

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

The Immutable JS docs reference the lazy operation of Seq. Particularly the following example:

```
var oddSquares = Immutable.Seq.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).filter(x => x % 2).map(x => x * x);

console.log(oddSquares.get(1));
```

It says filter is called 3 times and map is called twice. I don't understand the order of operations that would lead to the methods getting called 3 and 2 times respectively. In fact if I had to guess what the proper "lazy" action was I would have expected they wouldn't be called at all as they weren't necessary to perform the requested operation (locate 1 in the set). Can someone help me understand how the chained methods get called?

Comment: `filter` and `map` are both called only once. But when you access the second element of the `oddSquares` sequence, the callback that was passed to `filter` will need to be called thrice and the one passed to `map` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oddSquares.get(1)` fetches the second element from the `oddSquares`.

Which means that `.map(x => x * x);` should be called twice to produce the 2 elements.

For `.map` to get 2 elements as its input the `.filter(x => x % 2)` should produce 2 elements. As we can see the `filter` predicate filters odd numbers.

To get 2 odd numbers from the initial sequence `Immutable.Seq.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` we need to process 3 numbers: `1` which is odd, `2` which is even, `3` which is odd.

```
  Immutable.Seq.of     1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8
                       v   v   v 
filter(x => x % 2)     1 - - - 3
                       v       v 
   map(x => x * x)     1 - - - 9
                       v       v
            get(1)     - - - - 9
```

Comment: Of course, if it was really completely lazy, the `map` callback would only need to be called once to generate the element that is accessed.